# T-test and linear regression are significant but a grouped boxplot shows similar medians

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, t-test, boxplot

I did a mean differences test, the t-test gave me a p-value of 0.034 and a regression test gave me significant differences as well. But when I plot my data with a boxplot, I see that the medians are very similar between groups.
Is my analysis correct or could I be wrong? Are there really differences between the groups I analyzed?

````
Call:
lm(formula = variable_1 ~ ., data = regresión)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-1.297e-15 -1.972e-16 -1.096e-16 -6.400e-18  1.360e-14 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    3.783e-15  2.719e-16 1.391e+01   <2e-16 ***
variable2      1.000e+00  4.587e-17 2.180e+16   <2e-16 ***
variable3             NA         NA        NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.239e-15 on 125 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 4.754e+32 on 1 and 125 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16``` 


``` #t-test output
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  regesión$variable1 and regesión$variable2
t = -2.9421, df = 487.48, p-value = 0.003416
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.0391881 -0.2069565
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 3.210551  3.833623
````

[image]

Comment: What’s going on with the NA in your regression output? // The regression you’ve run and the t-test assess means, not medians. Means can be unequal while medians are equal.

Comment: There's something wrong with the linear model: it shows an essentially perfect fit with an intercept of 0 and a slope of exactly 1, to within machine precision. That suggests that variable1 is identical to variable2, which doesn't seem consistent with the t-test or the boxplots. The linear model also doesn't seem to account for the grouping of variable2 that you show in the boxplots. Please check your data and your code.

Comment: 1. A visual comparison of **medians** can easily be different from a formal test of **means**. (The big question is why you find that surprising.) 2. Something looks awry with your output, your regression and t-test don't seem consistent. Can you give the data? It could help in writing an answer.

Comment: I also suspect that you did something wrong. The Welch test says that means are 3.21 and 3.83, but boxplots look right-skew and medians are around 5, so I'd expect means to be *larger* than 5 (and my intuition says that these should not be significantly different unless you have a huge sample). The regression has no visible relation to the plot either, and a mysterious variable3 occurs there for which no explanation is given.

Comment: The t-test output says "data:  regesión$variable1 and regesión$variable2", the regression seems to use variable1 as response, whereas the t-test apparently compares it with variable2. These are very different things. Maybe it helps to give the code for the boxplot to see whether that's even different.